# How to avoid to use a fixed width in Container?

Tags: flutter

### My original problematic code:

Note the fixed width `width: 220.0,`.

```dart
ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:0.0),),
    InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 28.0,
                  child: Text('1')
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 40.0,
                  width: 220.0, // Must to have, otherwise, it overflows the Text 'AAAAAAAA' container on the right.
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(child: Text('This is very very very very very'
                        ' very very very long', 
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0), overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                      ),
                      Expanded(child: Text('This is very very very very very'
                        ' very very very long', 
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0), overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Container(
              height: 40.0,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('AAAAAAAA', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0)),
                ],
              )
            ),
          ],
        )
      ),
    ),
  ]
)
```

### My solution:

```dart
ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:0.0),),
    InkWell(
      onTap: () {},
      child: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0, horizontal: 10.0),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            CircleAvatar(
              radius: 28.0,
              child: Text('1')
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                height: 40.0,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('This is very very very very very'
                    ' very very very long', 
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0), overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                    Text('This is very very very very very'
                    ' very very very long', 
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0), overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis)
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              height: 40.0,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('AAAAAAAA', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 13.0)),
                ],
              )
            ),
          ],
        )
      ),
    ),
  ]
)
```

Comment: What do you mean by this "Expanded does not work with unbounded constraints from the reported errors." ?

Comment: @AjayS This is what I got when I remove `height` and `width` constraints. https://hastebin.com/cosamatuke.coffeescript To fix this, it's either provide constraints or removing `Expanded` class.

Comment: Use flex rather than fixed height and width

Comment: @RafiqulHasan thanks a lot for the comment. Can you show me the code how to do it? Just how to change my above code. Btw, I need `overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis` to work. Thanks.

Comment: If you have to use width, you can get device width using this. 
- MediaQuery.of(context).size.width

Comment: Suppose you want to give 2/3 height of your device in a widget and 1/3 in another container. You can use something like this.


Container(
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max, //set Maximum height to column
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(flex: 2,child: Text('VERY LONG TEXT', overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,))
      Expanded(flex: 1,child: Text('VERY LONG TEXT', overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,))
    ],
  ),
)

Comment: @RafiqulHasan Thanks for your detail reply. I have found the problem I made. To better explain `Expanded does not work with unbounded constraints`, I finally understand it's because I use a `ListView` and `Expanded` needs to have a height to work with `ListView`. This is nothing to do with `width`. Sorry about my unclear question description. I have put both my original problematic code and my solution code in detail in the question now (re-edited). If you have time, you can have a look and let me know if there is any better way than the solution I figured out. Thank you very much .

Comment: Looks Good. One tips : Try to break UI into small Widget. For example: You can write a function or static Util class which will return a Text widget or image Widget. This way can reuse code. And Code structure will be much understandable and won't look messy.

Comment: @RafiqulHasan Thanks a lot for your reply and review. Yeah, I did break UI to smaller widgets in the real code. Thanks. ^_^

Comment: @sgon00 My Pleasure!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't give a `width` for `Container` then it will automatically fill any space available:

[image: overflow example]

```
Container(
    height: 40.0,
    child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
            child: Text(
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
         )),
         Expanded(
             child: Text(
                      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.",
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
          )),
        ],
    ))
```

If you want to give a width then it's advised to use something like [MediaQuery](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html) to make sure the value is uniform across screen sizes for example:

```
Container(
  height: 40.0,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
  child: ...
```

Just make sure everything is wrapped up in a `MaterialApp` or `WidgetsApp` for `MediaQuery` to work:

[image: half size]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detail reply. My original question has some problems and unclear parts, the reason why I have to give width is because that container is inside a Row which has many children. With `MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2`, I think it still may overflow in smaller device because of other children in the same row. Is that possible to find out other children's widths automatically/programmable? so that I can do something like `width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - child1_width - child2_width`. something like that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you able to provide a layout example/diagram in your question?

Comment: I have found the problem I made. If I put every non-row children inside one row, it works fine. If I put a row child inside a row, it doesn't. I will share the detail code tomorrow. I have to sleep now, otherwise my wife will kill me...

Comment: Yeah things like Rows within Rows can act funny. Haha good luck!

Comment: Sorry that it takes so long. I have edited my question and put both problematic code and solution code in detail. You can have a look now. If you have any better suggestions, please let me know. Thanks a lot.